# Count odds in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

What would be the shortest way to count the number of odd numbers in a list of lists like this with arbitrary dimensions, not necessarily 5x5:

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

I tried, but i'd guess there's shorter:

```
counter = 0
for row in list_of_lists:
    for i in row:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you always have one level of flat lists inside the main list you can use an inner loop to flatten, summing the result of  each `i % 2` which will be 1 for odd and 0 for even numbers:

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

print(sum(i % 2 for sub in list_of_lists for i in sub))
```

Or use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to do the flattening:

```
from itertools import chain

print(sum(i % 2 for i in  chain(*list_of_lists)))
```

If you had arbitrary nesting, recursion would be an easy way to approach the problem:

```
def flat(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            for j in flat(i):
                yield j % 2
        else:
            yield i % 2

print(sum(flat(list_of_lists)))
```

Comment: Thanks @Padraic Cunningham! Very nice answer, and extremely quickly :)

Comment: Actually your original solution works already for size and number of lists.

Comment: @Zorgmorduk, the recursion would just be if you had lists inside lists inside lists  ...

Answer (score 1):

The numpy way of counting for a contrast:

```
import numpy as np
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

l = np.array(list_of_lists)
print len(l[l%2!=0])
```

`l[l%2!=0]` returns all the elements that satisfy the condition `l%2!=0` and `len()` counts it.

PS : This of course assumes that the list_of_lists is rectangular. For a solution that allows different length for each inner-list, see Padraic's answer.